# ip site digitalocean to cloudflare

Tags: nginx, web-server, ip, cloudflare

I have site with just an ip address instead a domain name
Is it possible my site use cloudflare service?
My site hosted at digitalocean 
My server use nginx

I've been searching through the net but no result
Please help 
Thank you

Comment: There will never be any result for this. The first thing CloudFlare asks you for, after your username and password, is your domain name.

Comment: What do you expect them to do for you?

Answer (score 3):

No you can't do this. CloudFlare works with domain names, not IP addresses.